# Was This Tournament All In Call Correct?

Tags: tournament

I played a hand in a local $100 buy-in tournament; I was wondering if one of the (3) players in the hand, played it correctly.

- blinds were $200/$400--no antes yet
- UTG, SOLID PLAYER/STACK SIZE $4,800. RAISES TO $1200
- HERO, SOLID PLAYER/STACK SIZE $14,100. 3-BETS TO $3,750 WITH AA
- VILLAN, NOT AWARE, PLAYS ONLY HIS CARDS/STACK SIZE $9,650.  CALLS $3,750
- UTG 4-BETS ALL IN FOR $3,600.
- HERO RAISES ALL IN FOR $10,350
- VILLAN IS ALL IN FOR $5,900.

RESULT:  UTG SHOWS AK OFFSUIT; HERO SHOWS AA; VILLAN SHOWS JJ.
OFF COURSE A JACK APPEARS ON THE FLOP AND WINS IT ALL.
WAS IT A CORRECT MOVE FOR THE VILLAN TO CALL THE HERO'S ALL IN?  THANKS.
 -

Comment: YOU LIKE CAPITALS?

Answer (score 1):

UTG is weak, why raise at that stack size if you had anything worth shoving?

VILLAIN knows UTG most likely has to at least call giving him some implied odds, solid call on the 3 bet.

UTG all in HERO re-shove, HERO shows way too much strength here and there is a chance that UTG has two overs (although it looks weaker than AK) VILLAIN calling is a mistake.

However there is a valid argument for calling. If HERO senses the weak UTG open he can have a wider range than his re-shove suggests. If VILLAIN believes HERO is capable of capitalizing on the short stack UTG player it can justify a call.

I disagree with this argument because re-shoving to isolate with someone behind you when you are weak is not great, especially when the person behind you is already relatively pot committed.

Comment: UTG isnt weak. 3x-ing of 12BB is very strong. Deepest effective stacks were 25BB. Getting jacks in is standard. Keep your answers simple.

Comment: I don't think jacks all in given this action is standard here at all, I would lay this down a huge percentage of the time in villains spot. I agree with you on UTG now though, for some reason I miscalculated his stack and though he had under 10BBs when I originally read the question.